# The sql query returns zero when I use NOT IN operator

Tags: sql

There are two tables

```
A(ESN_NO,MAKER, HANDSET, MODEL, FLAG, OFFER, STATUS, STATUS_UPDATEd_date) ,             
B(ESN_NO,MAKER, HANDSET, MODEL, FLAG, OFFER, STATUS, STATUS_UPDATEd_date)
```

I need to add data from the `bau_load` table into the `omh_esn_model_details_new` table without duplicates.

I added 80,000 rows into the A table.

Then to see the common `esn_no` I used an IN operator; this is the query:

```
select count(*) 
from A 
where esn_no in (select esn_no from B);
```

count came as 74,000--- so there are around 6000 new `esn_no`

But when I used a NOT IN operator:

```
select count(*) 
from B 
where esn_no not in (select esn_no from A);
```

count came as 0

```
select count(*) 
from A 
where esn_no not in (select esn_no from B);
```

count came as 0

and when i used this query

```
select count(*) 
from A 
where esn_no not in (select esn_no 
                     from A 
                     where esn_no in (select esn_no from B));
```

count came as 6000

So, I want to know why I did not return 6000 when I used the NOT IN operator?

Comment: They are likely `NULL` values.

Comment: can you explain it? please

Comment: use `NVL` where needed to replace those NULL values!